# Toggle a button on Click in React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I'm currently showing my button of categories. I want that when I click a single button it will be darken and will be active and when I click it again it will return to it's default style and not active..

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
    border: "1px solid black",
    borderRadius: "1em",
    boxShadow: "1px 1px",
  },
  scrollMenu: {
    overflow: "auto",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
  },
  buttonActive: {
    backgroundColor: "gray",
  },
}))

    const CategoryList = ({ categories }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const [myFilters, setMyFilters] = useState({
    filters: { category: [] },
  })
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10)
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0)
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    long: 120.9868052,
    lat: 14.6038269,
  })
const [ active, setActive ] = useState(false)

  //   const handleClick = (e, categoryId) => {
  //     e.preventDefault()
  //     console.log(categoryId)
  //   }

  const loadFilteredResults = (newFilters) => {
    console.log(newFilters)
    getProductsByCategory(location.long, location.lat, skip, limit, newFilters)
  }

  const clickFilters = (filterBy, categoryId) => {
    console.log("Product", filterBy, categoryId)
    const newFilters = {
      ...myFilters,
      filters: {
        [filterBy]: [...myFilters.filters[filterBy], categoryId],
      },
    }
    loadFilteredResults(newFilters.filters)
    setMyFilters(newFilters)
setActive(!active)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadFilteredResults(myFilters.filters)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className={classes.scrollMenu}>
      {categories.map((category) => {
        return (
          <Button
            key={category._id}
            className={active ? classes.button : classes.buttonActive}
            onClick={() => clickFilters("category", category._id)}
          >
            {category.name}
          </Button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default CategoryList
```

But what's happening is when I click a button all the other button turns dark. [image]

then when I click it again all will be on it's default again. How can I achieve that every button I click will turn dark then whhen I click it again it will go back to white again.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a boolean to control all button. You should use an id/index of button to control like this:

```
const [ active, setActive ] = useState(null)

const clickFilters = (filterBy, categoryId) => {
  ...
  setActive(active === categoryId ? null : categoryId )
}

className={active === category._id ? classes.button : classes.buttonActive}
```

Comment: tried this but when I click the button again it is still on white color. I want it to return on it's previous style

Answer (score 0):

Give the buttons a name, then create a dynamic map in state to track their dark/light status.

```
const [darkButtons, setDarkButtons] = useState({})

// the button code
<Button 
    name={category.[some unique property]}>
    className={darkButtons.[some unique property] ? classes.button : classes.buttonActive}
    ...
</Button>
```

In your click handler, something like,

```
const clickFilters = e => {
    // do everything else

    // this will toggle a boolean for the button by their name
    // so if you click one, it switches
    setDarkButtons({ ...buttonState, [e.target.name]: !buttonState[e.target.name]})

}
```

That will keep track of each button's dark state, dynamically.